# Deserialize dynamic XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

The `XML` below always comes in this format, but the elements under the `<Hit>` node are dynamic, the name or number of items could be different each time. Is it possible to get the elements under the `<Hit>` node dynamically.

```
<SearchResponse>
    <Response>
        <Qtime>3</Qtime>
        <HitsPerPage>10</HitsPerPage>
    </Response>
    <HitsCount>
        <total>33</total>
        <start>0</start>
        <end>10</end>
    </HitsCount>
    <Hits>
        <Hit>
            <id type=''>123</id>
            <eid type=''>456</eid>
            <Title type='t'>
                <![CDATA[title goes here]]>
            </Title>
        </Hit>
        <Hit>
            <id type=''>123</id>
            <oid type=''>456</oid>
            <Title type='t'>
                <![CDATA[title goes here]]>
            </Title>
            <Description type='s'>
                <![CDATA[Description goes here]]>
            </Description>
        </Hit>
    </Hits>
</SearchResponse>
```

Edit: here's the C# code, it's working fine and get the id from the `<Hit>` node since I already defined the property, but I need to get all of them dynamic.

```
[XmlRoot("SearchResponse")]
    public sealed class SearchResponse {
        [XmlElement("Response", Type = typeof(Response))]
        public Response[] Responses { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("HitsCount", Type = typeof(HitsCount))]
        public HitsCount[] HitsCount { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Hits", Type = typeof(Hits))]
        public Hits[] Hits { get; set; }


        public static SearchResponse GetSearchResponseObject(string xmlString) {
            try {
                var reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SearchResponse));
                var instance = (SearchResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                return instance;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                var asd = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Response {
        [XmlElement("Qtime")]
        public string Qtime { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("HitsPerPage")]
        public string HitsPerPage { get; set; }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class HitsCount {
        [XmlElement("total")]
        public string Total { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("start")]
        public string Start { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("end")]
        public string End { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Hits {

        [XmlElement("Hit")]
        public Hit[] Hit { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Hit {
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit 2: // Hit class code

```
public class Hit {

        // Since "id" is expected in the XML, deserialize it explicitly.
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        private readonly List<XElement> _elements = new List<XElement>();

        [XmlAnyElement]
        public List<XElement> Elements { get { return _elements; } }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a schema for this document?

Comment: Using linq-to-xml it should be pretty easy. Just query the 'Hit' XElements, loop through them querying the child XElements.

Comment: @DanField No, there's no schema specified to the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know what elements might be present in your `Hit` class, you can add a `List<XElement>` property to you class and attach the [`[XmlAnyElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to it.  It will then capture any and all unknown elements in the XML for the class.  Once the elements are deserialized, you can add API properties to query for elements with specific names, for instance:

```
public class Hit
{
    // Since "id" is expected in the XML, deserialize it explicitly.
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    private readonly List<XElement> elements = new List<XElement>();

    [XmlAnyElement]
    public List<XElement> Elements { get { return elements; } }

#region convenience methods

    public string this[XName name]
    {
        get
        {
            return Elements.Where(e => e.Name == name).Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        set
        {
            var element = Elements.Where(e => e.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (element == null)
                Elements.Add(element = new XElement(name));
            element.Value = value;
        }
    }

    const string title = "Title";

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this[title];
        }
        set
        {
            this[title] = value;
        }
    }

#endregion
}
```

Incidentally, you can eliminate your `Hits` class if you mark the `Hits` array with [`[XmlArray]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `[XmlElement]`, like so:

```
[XmlRoot("SearchResponse")]
public sealed class SearchResponse
{
    [XmlElement("Response", Type = typeof(Response))]
    public Response[] Responses { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("HitsCount", Type = typeof(HitsCount))]
    public HitsCount[] HitsCount { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Hits")] // Indicates that the hits will be serialized with an outer container element named "Hits".
    [XmlArrayItem("Hit")] // Indicates that each inner entry element will be named "Hit".
    public Hit [] Hits { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

The

```
    public string this[XName name] { get; set; }
```

Is an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).  See [Using Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx).  I added it so it would be easy to do things like:

```
var description = hit["Description"];
var title = hit["Title"];
```

The indexer looks for the first XML element with the specified name, and returns its [text value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If you don't want it, you can leave it out -- it's just for convenience.

Comment: Thanks, this working perfectly, but i'm not quite sure what's happening inside the 'Hit' class. i made some changes on your code, and it still working fine. could you please explain why you're using this part of code 'public string this[XName name]' , please check the latest update at my question to see the current code with the changes.